# Conditional in CSS "width is more than..."

Tags: css, conditional-statements, width

Is possible to make a conditional in **CSS** that checks if the width of (for example) `ul` is more than X px, and apply different styles, or is necessary *js*?

Thanks!

Comment: width of the viewport can be checked, but if you are looking for a particular element then it requires Js

Comment: Yes, and the width of a block (like an ul) is the full width of the parent, unless you give it a width yourself, in the stylesheet. So you really already know what width it is.

Comment: What you are asking for has been dubbed “element queries” … and doesn’t really exist in CSS yet, but there are some polyfills. https://www.google.com/search?q=css%20element%20queries

Comment: @MrLister nah, disagree, you won’t always know how wide an element is, just because you know the viewport width. Think of a list inside a `figure` element maybe, that itself (figure) is inline-block and therefor has its width determined by whatever image is actually used, or stuff like that.

Comment: @04FS A `figure` is only inline-block if you make it inline-block in the css. By default, it is a block, as is the `figcaption` inside.

Comment: @MrLister okay so then your point from before makes sense as long as we only create designs from now on where every element is block … great :-)

Comment: @04FS I did not say that. You're twisting my words now to make me look stupid, because you feel you are losing the argument! ;)

Comment: @MrLister your argument is completely pointless to begin with, as soon as we are _not_ dealing with a block element, which you can not even infer from the mere fact that the question was asked regarding a `ul` element.

Answer (score 1):

The following code may help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body{font-family: helvetica;}
        ul{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo hic, quis quasi consequatur laudantium voluptatibus. Illo soluta quam eum dolore esse inventore accusamus, amet ipsum at numquam, blanditiis enim! Ad!</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo hic, quis quasi consequatur laudantium voluptatibus. Illo soluta quam eum dolore esse inventore accusamus, amet ipsum at numquam, blanditiis enim! Ad!</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo hic, quis quasi consequatur laudantium voluptatibus. Illo soluta quam eum dolore esse inventore accusamus, amet ipsum at numquam, blanditiis enim! Ad!</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo hic, quis quasi consequatur laudantium voluptatibus. Illo soluta quam eum dolore esse inventore accusamus, amet ipsum at numquam, blanditiis enim! Ad!</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        var ulwidth = $('ul').width();
        console.log(ulwidth);
        if (ulwidth > 500) {
            alert('Width is greater than 500');
        }
        else {
            alert('Width is less than 500');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will help you on page load.

Answer (score 1):

In modern browsers you can use containers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/container.

Here's an example which you can (hopefully) test by resizing your browser window.

```css
ul {
  container-type: size;
  container-name: myul;
}

@container myul (min-width: 400px) {
  li {
    list-style-type: square;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Container CSS Sample</h1>

<ul>
  <li>Circle when small, square when big</li>
</ul>
```